# is it possible to master a stereo source to work perfectly with pro logic

Tags: 5.1, logic, theory, dolby, stereo-to-surround

greetings fellow audio enthusiasts and experts,

I was having a conversation with a friend and the following subject came up leading to this question.

- is it possible to master a stereo source specially adapted for a technology like pro logic 2 or dts connect to result with near perfect 5.1 output
- what would be needed to do this?
- would the sound be really distorted if played back in native stereo?

i'm leaning more towards theoretical possibility and what would be needed to do it then already existing technologies although both are interesting to read the answers to

Comment: DTS connect, when used from a stereo source is actually DTS Neo:6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dolby Pro Logic II and DTS Neo:6 are simulated (matrixed) multi-channel formats, and don't come close to discrete multi-channel as far as channel separation and quality is concerned.

So "near perfect 5.1 output" would be out of the question.

*Expanded on, 29July16:*

It has to do with what matrixed audio is: There are only 2 channels and they are "mixed" in particular proportions and phase-shifts to create the other three channels. In Pro Logic II, as an example, you start with L (left) and R (right), and the other three channels are then mixed as follows:

C (center) is an even mix of L and R.

Rear-Left is mostly L phase-shifted +90 degrees, plus some R phase-shifted -90 degrees.

Rear-Right is mostly R phase-shifted -90 degrees, plus some L phase-shifted +90 degrees.

So you see, there can be nothing in the center or rear channels that is not already in the left and right channels. Matter of fact, the person creating the mix has almost no control on what the final mix will sound like. It's a pre-canned audio illusion to give the feeling of surround, using only two discrete channels. Think about it - If it was possible to master PL2 audio to sound more discreet, don't you think the studios would have used it that way?

Here is a good Wikipedia explanation on matrixed audio. Pro logic II is at the bottom:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decoder

Comment: I understand that about the technology. what i was wondering specifically if it would be possible.. to " mix " a source in such a way it influences the logic aplied by DTS Neo:6 or Dolby Pro Logic II to come very close to regular 5.1 sources

Comment: Hi Dave. Ok, I have updated the answer with a better explanation.